# Gridview editform

Tags: devexpress

I have a Devexpress gridview with property enablecallbacks=false. When I open the editform and enter some data and click update, it loses the data entered but does the validation. How do I make the editform work retain the value?. I dont want the editform to lose the data during postback?. Any help?.

I have to have the edvexpress with this property to have another control inside the editform to work?.

Comment: Please specify what controls you are using in your edit form.

Comment: Would you share the problematic page/ASPxGridView markup and code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup routing for your edit function in the Gridview settings;

```
settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Controller", Action = "Action" };
```

You also need to call this from some button for example from your editform Example;

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "Name";
    settings.Text = "DELETE";
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ GridName.UpdateEdit(); }";
}).GetHtml()
```

However in your question it does not say in what framewoork you are woorking, provided examples are from MVC.